# Perforce: Command to view all submitted changelists I don't have yet

Tags: perforce

In P4V, on the Dashboard it shows the Folder status and "Not updated with the following changelists (NUM)". Below that it displays all of the submitted changelists I don't have yet. How can I view that same list of changelists from the Windows or PowerShell command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the details of your server version, try:

```
p4 cstat
```

Make sure you specify the right P4PORT, P4USER, and P4CLIENT when you run the command, corresponding to the connection information you use from P4V.

You're looking for the changelists that you "need" or are "partial". Those that you already "have" are of course not the ones you are interested in.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks like it can be parsed to get the information that I want, but what a horrible format! I wish the status was on the same line rather than the next line so it can be filtered more easily.

Comment: Actually, this output format, called "tagged" output, is intended to be easier to parse, not harder. Typically, though, tools built on Perforce don't parse tagged output directly; they built atop a scripting language like Perl or Python for which there are already libraries which parse this format.